# Gaining focus in a win forms app?

Tags: c#, focus

I feel like I'm commiting a cardinal sin by asking how to do this becuase in most instances it would be wrong and evil. But...

I have a winforms app that minimises to the systray when not being used I want to make it pop up and be the topmost window when it recieves a message from a server.

I can make it appear, but I can't get it to be the topmost window. (Setting topmost doesn't change it, but it does make it topmost once it's gained focus)

Does anyone know how to do this?, I wouldn't normally do this but a client has asked for this behavious so I have to implement it... :(

Comment: None of the suggested solutions seem to work, I've resorted to having a bubble pop up from a systray notifyIcon. at least that gets the users attention.

Answer (score 1):

If .Net's 'topmost' thing is not working, you may try getting this service directly from the 'SetWindowPos()' API of Windows. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195516) page for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bf3117f8-d83d-4b00-8e4f-7398b559a2dd/) around this issue on Microsoft's forums.

Normally, if the window is in your app, calling its BringToFront method should do the trick.

So normal order of operations:

1. make it visible
2. call BringToFront()
3. Set it TopMost

Comment: That doesn't work if your whole app is minimised, it probably only works if one of your own windows currently has focus.